# Green screen while pushing view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have a login screen view controller (nib), when user logs in it instantiates storyboard and pushes initial view controller, but while transitioning  to this initial vc there is green screen, when transition done main screen appears normally.
![enter image description here][1]

```
DMapViewController *mapVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"DMapViewController"
                                                       bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mapVC
                                     animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Problem was in calling [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; in viewDidLoad of DMapViewController;